# Laravel DB Query four tables join and group by only returns first row?

Tags: laravel, database, model-view-controller, eloquent

I have four tables, with four models for each component, one controller and a view I will post the code.

(prescription_tests) table and model same name.

```
id 
prescription_id 
test_id Index
description
user_id
```

(prescriptions) table and model same name.

```
id 
user_id 
reference
advices 
created_at
updated_at
```

(users) table and model same name.

```
id
name
```

(tests)table and model same name.

```
id Primary
test_name
```

My Controller Function :

```
class LaboratoryController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function index(){
        
       // $teststoday = Prescription_test::all();
        $teststoday = DB::table('prescriptions')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'prescriptions.user_id')
        ->join('prescription_tests', 'prescription_tests.prescription_id', '=', 'prescriptions.id')
        ->join('tests', 'tests.id', '=', 'prescription_tests.test_id')
        ->select('prescriptions.*', DB::raw('group_concat(prescription_tests.prescription_id)'), 'tests.test_name' ,  'users.name')
        ->where('prescriptions.created_at', Carbon::today())
       // ->orderByDesc('prescriptions.id')
        //->groupBy('prescriptions.id')
        ->get()->toArray();

          return view('laboratory.view',compact('teststoday'));
    }
    
}
```

My View Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        @forelse($teststoday as $testtoday)
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <div class="card-header">
                <p class="card-text"> Name:{{ $testtoday->name }} ID:{{ $testtoday->user_id }}</p>
                </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"> Diagnosis Test ID:- {{ $testtoday->id }}</p>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            @foreach ($teststoday as $test)
                  <li>{{ $test->test_name }}</li>
                     @if($loop->last)
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 150px;"></div>
                        <hr>
                      @endif
                  @endforeach
                            
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        @empty
            <p>No Posts Currently</p>
        @endforelse
    </div>
```

The Probelm is when I have have two or more entries in Prescription_tests with same prescription_id it shows only one of them or the first row. I want to concatenate all of the entries in prescription_tests with same prescription_id and add it to the card-bootstrap with one header and one id.

|Thankss

Comment: Check if the necessary data is there in all the tables you are joining. As you are using `join` which is inner join which expects the data to be there in all the tables. You can give a try to `leftJoin` if inner join is not you intended.

Comment: `group_concat` is an aggregate function so using it means to aggregate all rows to a single one. You need to use `groupBy` but include all other (non-aggregate) columns in the groupBy not just prescription.id

Comment: @harishdurga the data is there one hundred percent, however in my other view when I add to prescription tests I have to make two rows with same Prescrioptions_id, then they have same prescriptions_id and I want to aggregate or concatenate the rows which has same prescriptions_id in prescriptions_tests and return it to the view, but it only returns the first row with that Id, if I don't add group by it returns both rows no problem but makes two cards, I want them to be available in one card both rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you ->groupBy('prescriptions.id') you will have Only one line per prescriptions.id. Generaly it is use to count the number of line on other table.. you can count the number of prescription_test per prescription.id with this it is why you have only one line.

Maybe what you want it is to group by with ->groupBy('prescription_tests.id') ?